# Jquery & ajax autorize.net submit

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit, authorize.net

Hey all i am trying to figure out why i keep getting the error

**here was an error submitting the form. Please try again. parsererror**

when trying to submit my form to authorize.net

My **authsubmit** php code is this:

```
  <?PHP
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // Make sure this path is correct.
$transaction = new AuthorizeNetAIM('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');

$post_url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";

$transaction->amount        = $_POST['amount'];
$transaction->card_num      = $_POST['card_num'];
$transaction->exp_date      = $_POST['exp_date'];
$transaction->first_name    = $_POST['first_name'];
$transaction->last_name     = $_POST['last_name'];
$transaction->card_code     = $_POST['cvv'];
$transaction->address       = $_POST['address'];
$transaction->city          = $_POST['city'];
$transaction->state         = $_POST['state'];
$transaction->zip           = $_POST['zip'];
$transaction->invoice_num   = $_POST['invoice_num'];
//$transaction->currency_code   = $_POST['currency'];

$response = $transaction->authorizeAndCapture();

if ($response->approved) 
{
    echo "<h1>Success! The test credit card has been charged!</h1>";  
    echo "Transaction ID: " . $response->transaction_id;
} else 
{  
    echo "here is the error: " . $response->error_message;
}
 ?>
```

And my **authsubmit** php code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frm1").submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "authsubmit.php",
            data: $("#frm1").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg){
                alert("DONE! " + msg);

            },
            error: function(obj, status, e){
                alert("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again. " + status);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });

});
 </script>

 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form id="frm1" method="post">
 <fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>Invoice Amount</label>
        <input type="text" value="3.33" name="amount" size="15" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Invoice Number</label>
        <input type="text" value="23111" name="invoice_num" size="15" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Credit Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" value="4500000000009000" name="card_num" size="15" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Exp.</label>
        <input type="text" value="1212" name="exp_date" size="4" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CCV</label>
        <input type="text" value="782" name="cvv" size="4" class="text">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="bob" name="first_name" size="15" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="barker" name="last_name" size="14" class="text">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" value="123 street" name="address" size="26" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" value="hyyon" name="city" size="15" class="text">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <div>
        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" value="ca" name="state" size="4" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
       <label>Zip Code</label>
       <input type="text" value="45098" name="zip" size="9" class="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" value="US" name="currency" size="22" class="text">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
    <div class="form_result"> </div>
    </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

What am i missing here?

David

Comment: Where is your form ending? And submit tag??

Comment: Sorry it didnt include it in the post but it was there. Updated the OP. Thanks

Comment: Try this: success:function(data){alert("done"+data);},failure:function(){alert("error");}

Comment: @RajatSinghal: Doesnt seem to do anything now. Just keeps spinning then stopping without popping up anything.

Comment: What does the console say if `error : function (obj, status, e) { console.log(obj); console.log(status); console.log(e); }` ?

Comment: @RajatSinghal: the console says: **3.3345000000000090001212bobbarker782123 streethixsontn4509823111US----------------------here is the error: AuthorizeNet Error:
                Response Code: 3
                Response Subcode: 1
                Response Reason Code: 6
                Response Reason Text: The credit card number is invalid.**

Comment: If you are using a test credit card on a live server, it will claim the number is invalid.

Comment: Right that part i know what i would like to catch that in the return "error:" part along with the other errors so going back to my original question is how can i get the error to **come back into the ajax?**

Comment: The message from Authorize should be in one of the three error parameters, so use it from there. The response with this set `error : function (obj, status, e) { console.log(obj); console.log(status); console.log(e); }` was what?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the live server for your testing. This means unless you have set your account to use test mode all transactions are live. If you're using a test credit card, or any other invalid credit card number, it will result in the error message you are getting.

You need to do two things to effectively test an Authorize.Net integration:

1. Sign up for a [developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/). This allows you to test your code without incurring any fees.
2. Use the developer server for testing.

So:

```
$post_url = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
```

Becomes:

```
$post_url = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
```